# RegEx works in tester not on site using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a RegEx that returns true if the string starts with `/` or `http:` and only allows `alpha numeric characters`, the `dash` and `underscore`.  Any white space and any other special characters should fire a false response when tested.

Below works fine (except that it allows special characters, I have not figured out how to do that yet) when tested at https://www.regex101.com/#javascript.  Unfortunately returns false when I implement it in my site and test it with `/products/homedecor/tablecloths`.  What am I doing wrong and is there a better regEx to use that would accomplish my goals?

```
^(\\/|(?:http:))\S+[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$
```

Comment: what about all the `/` in the url ?

Comment: both anubhava and Avinash have helpful answers.  Thank you!  RegEx can be easy to over complicate and frustrating to figure out.   Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep unescaped hyphen at first or at last position in character class:

```
^(\/|(?:http:))[/.a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$
```

Or even simpler:

```
^(\/|http:)[/\w.-]+$
```

Since `\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

To match URL you may need to match DOT and forward slash as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `\S+` from your regex and put the hyphen inside the character class at the first or at the last. Note that `\S+` matches any non-space characters (including non-word characters).

```
^(\/|http:)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$
```